# Docker container application not accessible on the host at http://localhost:9393

Tags: bash, docker, containers

I need to make sure create volume for container, set environment variable CSVSERVER_BORDER to have value 'Orange' and make application accessible on http://localhost:9393.

the command I used:

```
docker run -d -p 80:9393 -e CSVSERVER_BORDER='Orange' -v /root/solution/inputFile:/csvserver/inputdata imageid
```

Where `/root/solution/inputFile` is my local directory

Answer (score 0):

The command should be:

```
docker run -d -p 9393:80 -e CSVSERVER_BORDER='Orange' \
  -v /root/solution/inputFile:/csvserver/inputdata \
  imageid
```

the change is in the ports section: -p <host_port>:<container_port>